# Problem with restoring webview state after app installation

Tags: java, android, webview, savestate

I have a simple android app with WebView which opens the site main page. I need to save WebView state when the user presses "home" or "main menu" buttons. And then, when user opens app from the homescreen or main menu I need to load this saved state.

Everything works fine except the first launch (after installation of built apk file): if I open app from main menu the WebView restores just fine, but if I try to open it from homescreen it starts to reload. Is there any ways to fix that? Thanks in advance.

P.S. if I install app from Android Studio (not from built apk file) everything works as I expect, so I am confused.

These are methods where I save and restore WebView:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        if (savedInstanceState != null)
            webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        else
            webView.loadUrl(getString(R.string.URL));
    }
```

```
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        webView.saveState(outState);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```